# Angular 8 using async pipe for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, angular, internet-explorer, asynchronous

I am using `*ngIf` with `async` pipe to show and hide HTML elements. It works on Google Chrome or Firefox. But it doesn't work on Internet Explorer, how can I make it work on IE?

Here is the source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbxpyp

Comment: Make sure that polyfills are not messing up.

Comment: Worked for me when I opened it in StackBlitz on IE 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the project you provide can work well in IE 11. It shows "Successfull Message" in all browsers. Is there any error in console when it doesn't work in IE? Have you followed [the steps](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768) of supporting Angular 8 in IE 11?

You need to follow the following steps to make Angular 8 app run in IE 11:

1. Create a new tsconfig `tsconfig-es5.app.json` next to `tsconfig.app.json` with the below contents:

   ```
   {
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5" 
     }
   }
   ```
2. In `angular.json` add two new configuration section under the `build` and `serve` target to provide a new tsconfig:

   ```
   "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
     "options": {
         ...
     },
     "configurations": {
       "production": {
           ...
       },
       "es5": {
         "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
       }
     }
   },
   "serve": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
     "options": {
         ...
     },
     "configurations": {
       "production": {
        ...
       },
       "es5": {
         "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
       }
     }
   },
   ```
3. Run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

   ```
   ng serve --configuration es5
   ```