# @HostListener('document:scroll', []) not working in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I have code:

```
@HostListener('document:scroll', [])
onScroll(): void {
    console.log('I am scrolled' + document.documentElement.scrollTop);
}
```

But in IE11 not working, chrome and edge are ok...
why? How fix it?

(Angular 8)

Comment: Do `window:scroll` instead of document.

Comment: I tryed like that... but not work...

Comment: Really? Interesting...do you have the right polyfills enabled in polyfills.ts?

Comment: Is console.log not getting logged in ie?

Comment: /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';
/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'web-animations-js'; 
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

Comment: yes, console.log in IE is clear :/

Comment: What if you just attach a good old fashioned document.eventListener js style? Since hostlistener is technically attached to the component.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it can work well in IE 11. I think it might be that you don't add support for IE 11 correctly in your angular app. Is there any error in console in IE? You could follow the steps in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380976/angular-8-using-async-pipe-for-internet-explorer-11/58387761#58387761) to support Angular 8 in IE 11. Besides, Angular 8 doesn't need the polyfills you mentioned in the comment.

Except the steps in the thread, the `browserslist` in my **package.json** is like below:

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 5 Chrome version",
    "last 5 Safari version",
    "last 5 Firefox version",
    "last 5 Edge version",
    "last 5 iOS version",
    "last 5 ChromeAndroid version",
    "IE 11",
    "> 1%"
]
```

Result:

[image]