# SCRIPT1002: Syntax error - IE11, problem with ngx-cookie-service with angular 8

Tags: npm, internet-explorer-11, angular8, angular-cookies, ngx-cookie-service

I have a problem with IE11 when I inject 'CookieService' on the 'providers' of 'app.module.ts'.
I got this message with freezing page on IE11:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
vendor.js (152116,1)
```

It works with all other navigators, I also tried 'ngx-cookie' and I got the same error.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Have you followed [the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380976/angular-8-using-async-pipe-for-internet-explorer-11/58387761#58387761) to support Angular 8 in IE 11? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue? So that we can have a test and see how to help. We can't locate the issue with only the wide error message.